# Backbone View in a Browserify Module - Not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browserify

I'm trying to make a minimally functional Backbone.js app by separating the View and Model declarations into modules (Browserify). My Code:

index.html

```
<head>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myDiv">Loading...</div>
</body>

<script type="text/template" id="myTemplate">
    Test Content
</script>
```

Model.js

```
var Backbone = require('backbone')
Backbone.$ = $

Model = Backbone.Model.extend({

});

module.exports = Model;
```

View.js

```
var _ = require('underscore')
var $ = require('jquery')
var Backbone = require('backbone')
Backbone.$ = $

View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#myDiv',
    template: _.template($('#myTemplate').html()),
    initialize: function(){this.el.append(this.$el.html(this.template()));},
});

module.exports = View;
```

main.js

```
var _ = require("underscore"); 
var Backbone = require("backbone"); 
var $ = require("jquery");
var View = require("./View");
var Model = require("./Model"); 
Backbone.$ = $;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var model = new Model();
    var view = new View({model: model});
});
```

Browserify at the console:

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js -d
```

The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Comment: One thought - in your view you use `this.el.append`... do you mean `this.$el.append`? I'm not familiar with `append` applied to raw DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without Browserify your code would not work.

Here's what happens. When the browser executes your page it processes `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` so it loads `bundle.js` and executes it right away *before creating the rest of the page.* This means that by the time the browser executes this line:

```
template: _.template($('#myTemplate').html())
```

Your `script` element with `id` set to `myTemplate` **does not yet exist**. So the jQuery selector selects no elements and running `.html()` on an empty set returns `undefined`. So the call above is equivalent to running `_.template(undefined)`, which leads to the error you get.

Solution: move the template so that it is before the `script` element that loads `bundle.js`.

---

As arbuthnott pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432888/backbone-view-in-a-browserify-module-not-working/45437023#comment77833465_45432888), you also want `this.$el.append` instead of `this.el.append`. You did not get an error there because that code did not get the opportunity to run due to the error you were getting.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. What is the most common practice: load the bundle.js before, or after the body?

Comment: The most common practice is to load things as soon *as possible* with "as possible" being most important. If it is not possible to load before `body` because you depend on elements that are going to exist only once `body` is processed, then you have to load `bundle.js` after it.

Comment: That's a viable method. There's really no *single way* to do it that is always best or even appropriate in all situations. I've run into cases where people were complaining that using domready caused them problems. It's not that domready is bad. It's just that it did not suit their needs.